# Laravel manual authentication: RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel manual authentication, I would like to limit failed login attempts (to avoid brute force) and I wonder if there is a built-in functionality for this in Laravel 10,
so I found the RateLimiter feature, but this RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts are always false even I make more than 3 submissions.
I'm not installed any auth starter kit (UI, breeze, justStream), I'm working just with manual authentication.

My Login Function

```
    public function login(LoginRequest $loginRequest)
    {

       //this is always false
       $this->checkTooManyFailedAttempts();

       $email = $loginRequest->email;
       $password = $loginRequest->password;
       $remember = (bool)$loginRequest->remember;
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_verified' => 1], $remember)) {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('auth.login.show')->with('error', 'The email and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.');
        }
    }

    public function throttleKey()
    {
        return Str::lower(request('email')) . '|' . request()->ip();
    }

    public function checkTooManyFailedAttempts()
    {
         dd(RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 3));//this is always false
        if (! RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 3)) {
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception('IP address banned. Too many login attempts.');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every time login fails, you need to use RateLimiter::hit to increment the number of total attempts.

You can also wish to use RateLimiter::clear after login successfully

```
  //...
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_verified' => 1], $remember)) {
        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
 } else {
      RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
      return redirect()->route('auth.login.show')->with('error', 'The email and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.');
 }
 //...
```